# Why only one equality sign for the ancestor (Google Datastore)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

> UserModel.query (*self.login* == login, *self.name* == name, *ancestor* = ancestor_key)

This is a *Python* statement to retrieve data from the *GAE datastore*. Can you explain why I use **one** equality sign (=) for the ancestor, and **two** signs (==) for other properties?

When I use two equality signs, a statement like `self.login == login` should return a boolean value, that is then passed to the function. But it doesn't work this way, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part of your question:

python lets you overload 'equals' (and less-than and greather-than and so on) for a class (and you can have it return anything, not just true/false), and ndb has done just that for Properties to return query FilterNodes. Check the source: https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/model.py#858

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up a comparison with an assignment.

See the docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop

The factory for creating a query object for this Kind takes an ancestor argument which defines the scope of the query for the given ancestor.  It also accepts a number of expressions that defines filters. The use of `self.login == login` is an expression defining a filter.

I don't understand the last part of your question.

Another way of defining the query would be

`UserModel.query(ancestor=ancestor_key).filter(self.login==login)`

The ability to supply filters in query() is just a short cut for this form.